# automatic conversion between stl vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl, template-argument-deduction

What I want is to copy an `std::vector<int>` to another `std::vector<myStruct>` with assignment operator in which `myStruct` can be assigned an `int`. So I wrote this piece of code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct myStruct
{
   myStruct(int& a) : _val(a) { }
   myStruct(int&& a) : _val(a) { }

   myStruct& operator=(int& a)
   {
      _val = a;
      return *this;
   }

   int _val;
};

int main()
{
   vector<int> ivec;
   ivec.push_back(1);
   vector<myStruct> svec = ivec;

   return 0;
}
```

And it gives me error as it cannot find a valid conversion between `std::vector<myStruct>` and `std::vector<int>` although `int` can implicitly be converted to `myStruct`. On the other hand, assign operator cannot be declared outside the class so I deduce writing an operator manually is not an option. So what should I do in this situation?

*** UPDATE:
As `Blastfurnace` and others said this can be solved using this code instead of assignment:

```
vector<myStruct> svec(ivec.begin(), ivec.end());
```

But imagine the situation in which I want to write a library and want to handle this in the library itself so the user can just write `std::vector<myStruct> svec = someFunction()` in which `someFunction` returns `std::vector<int>`. Isn't there any solution for this?

Comment: You can use `vector<myStruct> svec(ivec.begin(), ivec.end());` instead.

Comment: @Rostislav: Post that as an answer, I submitted the same thing a few seconds after you.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks :) I also added some more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your best bet is having a conversion function**

```
std::vector< myStruct> convertVector( const std::vector< int> & other)
{
    return std::vector< myStruct> ( ivec.begin(), ivec.end() );
}
```

that would automatically use return value optimization so no overhead for copying the data twice (you just copy data once instead when you iterate the "other" vector).

---

*Just for the sake of completeness:*

By using custom datatypes it is possible adding custom type conversion but I guess that's generally a bad Idea and you may not be interested in, anyway:

```
class IntVector: public std::vector<int>{
    public:
    //conversion operator (note a VERY BAD IDEA using this, may come in handy in few cases)
    operator myStructVector () { 
        return convertVector(*this); 
    }
}

class myStructVector: public std::vector< myStruct>{
    //....
};
```

usage:

```
int main()
{
    IntVector ivec;
    ivec.push_back(1);
    myStructVector svec = (myStructVector)ivec;

    return 0;
}
```

I would discourage going this way anyway ^^

Comment: Guess there is no way then, I'll choose your answer as it has more information ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the constructor overload that takes an iterator range:

```
vector<myStruct> svec(ivec.begin(), ivec.end());
```

Comment: I am sure this will work, but imagine the situation in which I want to write a library and want to handle this in the library itself so the user can just write `std::vector<myStruct> svec = someFunction()` in which someFunction returns `std::vector<int>`. Isn't there any solution for this?

Comment: @Sinapse: I don't _think_ that's possible but someone with a bigger brain than I may come up with a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll tell the users to get the vector like this if I didn't find anything good ;)

Comment: @Sinapse you cannot assign between vectors with different parameter type.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `vector<myStruct> svec(ivec.begin(), ivec.end());` instead.

You could also use `std::copy(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), std::back_inserter(svec));` or `svec.assign(ivec.begin(), ivec.end());` as it might be better in case you assign multiple times as it can reuse the capacity of the `vector<myStruct>` after it was cleared.